# Error while creating tweet table in Hive

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive, flume

I am trying to do twitter sentiment analysis using Hadoop, Flume and Hive.
While creating the tweet table with tweets.sql file (using hive), got this error.
Command :

```
hive -f tweets.sql
```

Error

```
which: no hbase in   (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111/bin:/hadoop/Flume/bin:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/hadoop/sbin:/hadoop/bin:/usr/lib/hive/bin:/usr/lib/derby/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111/bin:/hadoop/Flume/bin:/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:/hadoop/sbin:/hadoop/bin:/usr/lib/hive/bin:/usr/lib/derby/bin)

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-common-2.1.0.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe
```

Also I have added the json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies to the hive lib folder and mapreduce lib folder but no effect.

tweets.sql

```
--create the tweets_raw table containing the records as received from  Twitter
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Mytweets_raw (
id BIGINT,
created_at STRING,
source STRING,
favorited BOOLEAN,
retweet_count INT,
retweeted_status STRUCT<
text:STRING, 
user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,

entities STRUCT<
urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
text STRING,

user STRUCT<
screen_name:STRING,
name:STRING,
friends_count:INT,
followers_count:INT,
statuses_count:INT,
verified:BOOLEAN,
utc_offset:INT,
time_zone:STRING>,

in_reply_to_screen_name STRING

) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets';

-- create sentiment dictionary

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dictionary (
type string,
length int,
word string,
pos string,
stemmed string,
polarity string
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION '/data/dictionary';
-- loading data to the table dictionary

load data inpath 'data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv' INTO TABLE dictionary;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE time_zone_map (
time_zone string,  
country string
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/data/time_zone_map';

-- loading data to the table time_zone_map

load data inpath 'data/time_zone_map/time_zone_map.tsv' INTO TABLE       time_zone_map;
-- Clean up tweets

CREATE VIEW tweets_simple AS
SELECT
id, 
cast ( from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(concat( '2014 ',      substring(created_at,5,15)), 'yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss')) as timestamp) ts,
text,
user.time_zone 
FROM Mytweets_raw
;
CREATE VIEW tweets_clean AS
SELECT 
id,
ts,
text,
m.country 
FROM tweets_simple t LEFT OUTER JOIN time_zone_map m ON t.time_zone =  m.time_zone;
-- Compute sentiment

create view l1 as select id, words from Mytweets_raw lateral view  explode(sentences(lower(text))) dummy as words;

create view l2 as select id, word from l1 lateral view explode( words ) dummy as word ;

create view l3 as select 
id, 
l2.word, 
case d.polarity 
when  'negative' then -1
when 'positive' then 1 
else 0 end as polarity 
from l2 left outer join dictionary d on l2.word = d.word;

create table tweets_sentiment as select 
id, 
case 
when sum( polarity ) > 0 then 'positive' 
when sum( polarity ) < 0 then 'negative'  
else 'neutral' end as sentiment 
from l3 group by id;

-- put everything back together and re-name sentiments...

CREATE TABLE tweetsbi 
AS
SELECT  
t.*,
s.sentiment 
FROM tweets_clean t LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets_sentiment s on t.id = s.id;

-- data with tweet counts.....

CREATE TABLE tweetsbiaggr 
AS
SELECT 
country,sentiment, count(sentiment) as tweet_count 
FROM tweetsbi
group by country,sentiment;

-- store data for analysis......

CREATE VIEW A as select country,tweet_count as positive_response from  tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='positive';

CREATE VIEW B as select country,tweet_count as negative_response from tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='negative';

CREATE VIEW C as select country,tweet_count as neutral_response from tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='neutral';

CREATE TABLE tweetcompare as select A.*,B.negative_response as negative_response,C.neutral_response as neutral_response from A join B on A.country= B.country join C on B.country=C.country;

-- permission to show data in Excel sheet for analysis ....

grant SELECT ON TABLE tweetcompare to user hue;
grant SELECT ON TABLE tweetcompare to user root;
-- for Tableau or Excel
-- UDAF sentiscore = sum(sentiment)*50  / count(sentiment)
-- context n-gram made readable
```

bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_111
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/hadoop
export FLUME_HOME=/hadoop/Flume
export FLUME_CONF_DIR=$FLUME_HOME/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$FLUME_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/FLUME_HOME/lib/*
export MAVEN_HOME=/apache-maven-3.3.9
export PATH=$PATH:$MAVEN_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export HIVE_HOME=/usr/lib/hive
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/HIVE_HOME/lib/*
export DERBY_HOME=/usr/lib/derby
export PATH=$PATH:$DERBY_HOME/bin
```

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: share sample sql file?

Comment: Please,  check it now.

Comment: the error states that it can't find hbase in the $PATH env variable. have you installed hbase?

Comment: you are not using hbase in script and the log shows hbase path error. try command hive --auxpath <path>/hcatalog-core.jar -f tweets.sql

Comment: Thanks, hbase problem is solved but it still gives the same exception. " Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe ".
Please help in this part.

Comment: Can you please tell which <path> you are referring in the command. ? @RahulSharma

Comment: I  downloaded JsonSerDe jar separately, however I cannot locate hcatalog-core.jar in it. can you please tell me how to mention it then?

Comment: I mean json-serde jar. As HIve doesn't provide any library for json serde so you need to add it by your own.

Comment: Even after adding, it gives the same error. @RahulSharma